# How to change button state based on *ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

in the below code, i want to do the following

```
if index is equal to 0 the text of the button should be info and enabled
```

and

```
    if index is equal to 1 the text of the button should be INFO and disabled
```

please have a look at me attempt below and let me know the ansewer

**code**:

```
td *ngFor="let application of applications;let index=index">
    <p> 
        <button (click)="showInfoWindow(application)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
        *ngIf = "index == 1; else INFO">info</button>
    </p>
    <ng-template #INFO disabled>
        INFO.
      </ng-template>
</td>
```

Comment: Does it mean there are only two elements in the `applications` array?

Comment: @MichaelD yes..but i would like to achieve what i have explained in the question regardless of the numbers of the application

Comment: What do mean by "_regardless of the numbers_"? So enabled and 'info' if index=0 and disabled and 'INFO' for _anything other index_?

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the condition using ternary operator for label and use `[disabled]` property to enable/disable the button. You could take advantage of `0` being falsy in JS.

Try the following

```html
<td *ngFor="let application of applications; let index=index">
  <p> 
    <button (click)="showInfoWindow(application)" [disabled]="!!index" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
      {{ !!index ? 'INFO' : 'info' }}
    </button>
  </p>
</td>
```

#### Update: Using `*ngIf`

```html
<td *ngFor="let application of applications;let index=index">
  <p> 
    <button *ngIf="index; else enabled" (click)="showInfoWindow(application)" disabled class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
      INFO
    </button>
    <ng-template #enabled>
      <button (click)="showInfoWindow(application)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
        info
      </button>
    </ng-template>
  </p>
</td>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nogi6b?file=src/app/app.component.html)

#### Update: debug current index

It's much easier and quicker to directly render the index in the template rather than to console.log the current index.

```html
<td *ngFor="let application of applications; let index=index" style="padding: 5px; border-right: 1px solid #000000;">
  Current index: {{ index }}
  ...
</td>
```

If you however insist on printing into console, you could define a function in the controller and pass the current index to it using interpolation.

**Controller**

```js
printIndex(index: number) {
  console.log(index);
}
```

**Template**

```html
<td *ngFor="let application of applications; let index=index">
  {{ printIndex(index) }}
  ...
</td>
```

But beware: this might extremely misleading as the function will be triggered for each change detection cycle with default change detection strategy.

Comment: can we achieve that using *ngIf??

Comment: i mean the code you posted is edifying, but to achive the same results with ngIf

Comment: @user2121: Yes you can but I'm not sure why you'd want to do that. It'd only lead to duplicated code for the button element. I've updated the answer.

Comment: do you mean in such scenario we do not need to use ngIf!!

Comment: please let me know why you preceded index bt !! in the code you posted,  {{ !!index ? 'INFO' : 'info' }} what does it mean

Comment: @user2121: **1.** You don't need `*ngIf` as evidenced by the solution 1 in the answer. **2.** `!!` is used to convert a JS object to boolean. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/784946/6513921

Comment: i tried the 1st soultion you posted and it always prints INFO!!

Comment: I've included working examples for both the variants.

Comment: would you please tell me how to display the value of the index in the browser using console.log??

Comment: @user2121: Do you need it to check the current index of the iteration?

Comment: @user2121: I've updated the answer and the working example.

Comment: for the 2nd code you posted it always displays INFO capitalized the code i ihave is as follows<p> 
         <button (click)="showInfoWindow(application)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
         *ngIf="index; else enabledButton" disabled>"INFO</button>
        </p>
        <ng-template #enabledButton>
         <button (click)="showInfoWindow(application)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">info</button>
        </ng-template>
       </td>

Comment: It works in the Stackblitz. Please try to create a working example with the error.

Comment: i posted this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66900549/button-label-is-not-comformable-with-the-value-set-in-button-tag             the Update: debug current index you posted is correct